# Mejor anotación de datos para un decimal (18,2)

Tags: c#

Tengo una columna dentro de mi servidor SQL Server 2008 con tipo de Decimal(18,8). Pero en el marco de entidades, ¿cuál es la mejor validación de anotación de datos que puedo aplicar a esta propiedad, dentro de mi aplicación web asp.net MVC?

Comment: Si estás usando EF te recomiendo las validaciones usando FluentApi de lo contrario DataAnnotations. Espero que te ayude.

Comment: @FredyAdrianoJimenezMartinez como fluentApi